# Connectify network for android

Tags: connectify

I have a wired internet access on my win xp laptop. And want to share it to my HTC android smartphone. So, I've installed Connectify Hotspot Pro 3.7.1, created a network, but my android even doesn't see that network. However, another windows based laptop sees it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because Android can neither connect nor "see" ad-hoc networks. There's supposedly a work around in which you install some third party software on your Android device, but it only works on a small list of phone models. A quick Google search will lead you to the page. Sorry, I'm on my tab right now otherwise I'd link it here.

EDIT:
Found the link to a similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100928/how-to-connect-android-wifi-to-adhoc-wifi